# Call int() function on sublists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of lists that I want to call the function int() on to see if all the elements in the sublists are integers. Specifically, I want to call int() on the first sublist. I have a list that is like `[["a","1","2","3"],["1","2","3","4"]]`. If the first element in the sublist is not a number, then I will return nothing. However, if it is, then I will report that the sublist is invalid. My code is below:

```
new_list = [int(i) for i in l]
print(new_list)
```

This gives me `TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'`.

Comment: This is contradictory. You say you want to call `int()` on the first sublist, but then you say you want to check the first element of each sublist. Which is it?

Answer (score 2):

In your current code `i` is referring to each list object inside your list, so the error is informing you that `int()` doesn't take a `list`... You need to access the first element of that list, eg: `i[0]`...

You could wrap the `int` conversion in a try/except and just catch and print the error, eg:

```
for row in your_list:
    try:
        int(row[0])
    except ValueError as e:
        print('Invalid:', e)
```

You could also use (without try/except):

```
for row in your_list:
    if row[0].isdigit():
        print('Invalid:', row)
```

Comment: -1 is a number, and an int, but `'-1'.isdigit()` is False. In general, trying to figure out and code up logic for "could this thing be parsed the way I hope to parse it?" is harder and buggier than just trying to parse it.

Comment: Anyway, the first half answers one of the two possible questions the OP could be asking, and explains it well.

Comment: @abarnet good points... I should really have explained those caveats - but had actually forgotten I had answered this anyway...

Comment: When `row[0]` is `"a"`, this will result in `Invalid: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'`, which is not much help; instead try `print('Invalid:', e.args[0].split(':')[1].strip())`

Answer (score 0):

You get this typeerror because you have two lists within your list. so you would need an additional `for` in your list-comprehension.